# audio play/pause toggle not working in react

Tags: reactjs, audio, audio-player

```
function MusicCard() {
const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

const url = "http://localhost:4000/musics/myMusic.mp3";
const audio = new Audio(url);

const play = () => {
    setPlaying(true);
    audio.play();
};

const pause = () => {
    setPlaying(false);
    audio.pause();
};

return (
    <div className="music-card">
        <div className="music-card_image-con">
            <button style={{
                backgroundImage: `url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}music-image.jpg)`
            }} onClick={playing ? pause : play}>{ playing ? <FaPause /> : <FaPlay /> }</button>
        </div>
        <div className="music-card_info-con">
            <div className="music-card_info-name">
                <h3>music name</h3>
                <p> - </p>
                <p>Singer</p>
            </div>
            <div className="music-card_info-seekbar">
                <input type="range" style={{
                    width: "100%"
                }} />
            </div>
        </div>
        <button className="music-card_actions-btn"><FaEllipsisV /></button>
    </div>

);
}
```

what is the problem with this toggle? when I press the play button it plays the music but when I pres it again it starts another session of the music like using another new Audio() method instead of pausing it!

**Edit:** the pause doesn't work and play starts new session of Audio every time starting to play

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setPlaying` call causes re-rendering and initializes a new instance of `Audio` every time the component re-renders, you'll have to call `useRef` to persist the `Audio` instance between each render:

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react";

function MusicCard() {
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

  const url = "http://localhost:4000/musics/myMusic.mp3";

  const audioRef = useRef(new Audio(url));

  const play = () => {
    setPlaying(true);
    audioRef.current.play();
  };

  const pause = () => {
    setPlaying(false);
    audioRef.current.pause();
  };

  return (
    <div className="music-card">
      <div className="music-card_image-con">
        <button
          style={{
            backgroundImage: `url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}music-image.jpg)`,
          }}
          onClick={playing ? pause : play}
        >
          {playing ? <FaPause /> : <FaPlay />}
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="music-card_info-con">
        <div className="music-card_info-name">
          <h3>music name</h3>
          <p> - </p>
          <p>Singer</p>
        </div>
        <div className="music-card_info-seekbar">
          <input
            type="range"
            style={{
              width: "100%",
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <button className="music-card_actions-btn">
        <FaEllipsisV />
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MusicCard;
```

Comment: thanks. it works. I have another question. Is there a way I could play the music file from server before full file load? I mean something like YouTube music. I want to load the music when it's being played.

Comment: I'm not an expert in audio playback, but I would suspect what you're trying to achieve is already the default behavior. If it's not the case feel free to start another question so somebody else can help answer. Cheers!

Comment: I opened another one and no one answered. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67882689/15694279